# Using inner join instead of subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I wrote a query using a subquery, but I wonder if there is any way to write it using only inner join (or other joins) since it's more efficient.

```
/*2.    List the name of the sales rep who serves the most customers*/

select Sr.REP_NUM, Fname, Lname, count(cust_num) As TotalCustomers from employee Em
inner join SALESREP Sr on Sr.REP_NUM = Em.EMP_Num
inner join Customer Cu on Cu.REP_NUM = Sr.REP_NUM
group by Sr.REP_NUM, fname, lname
having count(Cu.rep_num) = (select max(AllReps.MostReps) from
(select count(rep_num) As MostReps from Customer group by rep_num) As AllReps)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using inner join:

```
select * from
(select Sr.REP_NUM, Fname, Lname, count(cust_num) As TotalCustomers from employee Em
inner join SALESREP Sr on Sr.REP_NUM = Em.EMP_Num
inner join Customer Cu on Cu.REP_NUM = Sr.REP_NUM
group by Sr.REP_NUM, fname, lname) As AllCounts
inner join
(select max(AllCus.MostCusts) As Most from
(select count(cust_num) As MostCusts from Customer group by rep_num) As AllCus) As MaxCusts
on MaxCusts.Most = TotalCustomers
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TOP (1)` or `TOP (1) WITH TIES`.  That should work better than the `HAVING` clause:

```
select top (1) with ties Sr.REP_NUM, em.Fname, em.Lname, count(*) As TotalCustomers
from employee Em join
     SALESREP Sr
     on Sr.REP_NUM = Em.EMP_Num join
     Customer Cu
     on Cu.REP_NUM = Sr.REP_NUM
group by Sr.REP_NUM, fname, lname
order by count(*) desc;
```

Comment: thanks. why exactly it shoud work better that the HAVING clause? Efficiency?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)? You can easily compare the Execution Plans of both queries and see how the Estimated Subtree Cost differs...as well as actually running both and seeing how the real execution times differ. Display Estimated Execution Plan (Ctrl + L). Include Actual Execution Plan (Ctrl + M).

Comment: @fnklstn there a fewer passes through the data using this `top(1) with ties` than with your subquery approach - I believe that is the claim. There is nothing inherently wrong in using a having clause, but to do so (here)  requires a second pass through the data. However, as an offset to those savings, there is an order by required.

Comment: not the best solution since there might be more than 1 sales representative witth the same amount of max

Comment: @fnklstn . . . If you want all with the max, then use `TOP (1) WITH TIES`.  If you only want one, then use `TOP  (1)`.  I mention that in the answer.